# Atalasoft DotImage Licensing

Tags: .net, image-processing, licensing, data-acquisition

I have been trying to find decent Image Acquisition + Image Processing solution at a bargain price.

I have looked at names like Kodak, Global360, Iris.

What I found with all these vendors is that they are very, very, very expensive.

I have also found that the SDK API licenses are just as expensive, if not more.

Please see [Atalasoft](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/purchase/default.aspx)

Is there a decent open source image acquisition and image processing component API out there?

I know that the development and support for the software can be hectic.
But is it worth the $$$ to develop ones own solution as to purchase a complete solution.

Thanks

Comment: For Photo image processing and a WinForms viewer, DotImage Photo from Atalasoft is now free http://www.atalasoft.com/photofree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV)? (See also [the google](http://www.google.com/search?q=opencv)).
From the featureset of what you linked OpenCV can do quite a bit of that, and it is [open source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/).